# How to validate youtube url, if the video has been deleted or videoid is incorrect using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, youtube

I want to validate youtube url's not for regex, but for whether it has been deleted or flagged and hence not playing. It could also be the case that the youtube url is formatted correctly(passes the regex test), but has an invalid video id. Is there a way of finding this out without using youtube api's and simply by javascript(maybe xmlhttprequests?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find if video id is invalid or deleted without using Youtube API.

You can try this out:

```
const videoID = 'QMg39gK624'; 
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/${videoID}`,
    success: function() {
        //it exists!
    },
    error: function(jqXhr) {
        if(jqXhr.status == 400) {
            //it doesn't exist
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There seems to be a way by checking for thumbnails of the video, https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg, if this returns status 200, the video exists and returns 404 or any other status then the video is invalid. But I am not sure if this is the accepted way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api?rq=1

Comment: There's a dedicated API to check this. Don't see good reason try to overpass this.

Comment: Did you solve? IS there a way to skip the removed vídeo from the list?